# Paypal Integration with iOS

Tags: ios, paypal

I am developing the iOS application and wants to use Paypal.
Where to define the merchant details?

Comment: Are you using the classic or REST api?

Comment: @richerlariviere: I just downloaded the PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App, replaced my client id for sandbox environment but don't know where to put merchant details.

Comment: I got the sample app form here: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK

Comment: Hello All is there any way out??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dave from PayPal here.

@Raj_216 your client ID, [which you have obtained from the PayPal Developer site](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK#credentials), is sufficient to identify your merchant.

Comment: Ohh!! Thank you. I thought that I need to provide some email Id or merchant Id for that.

Answer (score 0):

In **ZZMainViewController.m**, you can customize the *payPalConfig* object which contains merchant details.

Comment: I fount only merchantName, merchantPrivacyPolicyURL and merchantUserAgreementURL there. Where to provide merchant email or merchant Id?

Comment: PayPalConfiguration.h contains all the properties you can use. But I didn't see an email field.

Comment: Ok so what should I do to make a payment against my merchant? How my app will identify the merchant?